# Excel - Copy Hundreds of Cells based on Row Above

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel,
I want to copy

```
    ---------------------------------------------
    | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
    ---------------------------------------------
    | One      | Two      | Three    | Four     |
    ---------------------------------------------
```

To here

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Column A | Column F | Column C | Column E | Column D | Column B | 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |          |          |          |          |          |          |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Like this

```
     -------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Column A | Column F | Column C | Column E | Column D | Column B | 
     -------------------------------------------------------------------
     | One      |          | Three    |          | Four     | Two      |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How may I do this? I have hundreds of cells. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are your columns out of order? It's not very clear - are those the actual columns or just your header names for it.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: It would help if you create an actual table with a sample of what you want, and paste an image or a link to an image.

Comment: if I am understanding what you want, it may be be simple. In the first data (nonheader) row of the new column A, type = and then click on the first corresponding row of the old column A. Hit enter. Do the same for columns C, D, and B. Then select the first five columns of the row you just created, grab the handle at the lower right corner, and drag down.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are headers and your information is layed out as below, use the following formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($B$2:$E$4,ROW($A2),MATCH(F$9,$B$2:$E$2,0)),"")
```

I placed that in F10 and copied to the right and down as far as I needed.  I used IFNA to produce empty cells when the header did not match on in A2 to E2.  It will still show errors if you copy the formula down more rows than you have source data.  if you want to get rid of those error messages as well then change `IFNA` to `IFERROR`.

`ROW($A2)` is acting as a simple row counter as you move copy down.  it will depend on the number of header rows and how you define your look up range as to whether or not you will want to use A2, A1 or some other starting number/

[image]